# I have my react app in codesandbox . How can I deploy from sandbox

Tags: reactjs, github, codesandbox

I have my react app in codesandbox . How can I deploy from codesandbox . Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Codesandbox currently allows for a couple deploy options: Zeit and Netlify.  I have successfully deployed to Netlify.  Did take a few loops through deploy - log - fix to get it running.  I'm currently using Google Firebase Firestore as the backend.

Comment: In particular, all import paths need to be relative - since the deployment will be to shared servers.  I hate relative paths - to easy to miss when copied/moved - but worth the day cleaning up to get deployed.